# Piecewise defined function of two variables that has partial derivatives but is not differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> Let 
>   $$f(x,y)=\cases{0 & if $x=y$\\7x-3y & otherwise }.$$
>   Show $f_1(0,0) = 7$ and $f_2(0,0) = -3$, but $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

I found $f_1$ and $f_2$ by definition of partial derivative using the limit and found the values. I also reckoned that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$. So how can I argue that $f$ is not differentiable? Is that because $f_1$ is not the same as $f_2$? Please clear my confusion.

Comment: what are $f_1$ and $f_2$?

Comment: partial derivative of f with respect to x and to y, respectively

Comment: oh I didn't know that notation. I thought it was $f_x,f_y$.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion? I tried doing it with linear approximation and take the limit but limit still turns to be 0 which makes the function differentiable at (0,0).

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the partial derivatives exist doesn't necessarily mean that the function is differentiable. You have to check that there is no such linear map $A : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that:

$$\lim\limits_{||h|| \rightarrow 0} \frac{||f(h) - f(\textbf{0}) - Ah||}{||h||} = 0$$

Comment: Sorry. This still confused me. I tried but it did not come up right. I calculated the linear approximation l(x,y) = 0 +7(x-0) -3(y-0) = 7x - 3y. For f to be diff at (0,0), limit of [f(x,y) - l(x,y)]/(x^2 + y^2)^0.5 must be equal to 0. But when I extended that, the numerator is 0, making the limit 0. I don't really understand the linear map you talked above because in my class the professor did not mention it. Can you please explain it the other way or go a little more in depth with the linear map A you talked about?

Comment: Well, the map $ A $ is the differential of $ f $, so your professor must have mentioned that. The limit that I wrote is the definition of the differential. If it exists, then all of the partial derivatives exist and the map $(f_x (0). f_y(0))^T$ is the candidate for our differential. All you need to check is that the limit doesn't exists or isn't equal to 0 with for $ A = ((f_x (0). f_y(0))^T) $